# How do I get the path to a file in Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, path

I'm creating a simple web app on my local machine using XAMPP. Basically, I want to check if a file exists, but I do not know how to get the path of the file.

If I do the following, it will say that this file exists, which is true.

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ProjectName\\web\\files\\filename.txt";
```

However, this path is no good if I move the project from one computer to another, as the path won't be the same. What I'm asking is, what is the shortcut that I can use to get the location of the file. I know in PHP it would be something like

```
path = base_url()."files\filename.txt";
```

I can't really put into words what I am trying to ask, but I think people will get the idea.

Edit:

I'm using Netbeans too if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is `web` the document root of the web application? E.g. is `WEB-INF` a subdirectory of `web`, and `files` is a top-level directory inside your `.war` file? If so, use [`Servlet.getResourceAsStream("/files/filename.txt")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to find where your path really is is to do the following, because every application server handles the file handles a bit differently:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Like this, you open a file handle on the current directory and you know where you are located. From there on, you know how to navigate.
Be aware, that this is a dirty trick to find your starting point only. Depending on what you want to achieve, you are better of using the application server infrastructure to deal with files.

In case you are wondering on how to get the base url which you refered to, this one is stored in the request context of your servlet request:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Comment: The current directory can be anything, and can change between servers, so that's not the right way to go. [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) returns the URL used to access the web server, and has nothing to do with file structure on the web server. So, both parts of the answer are *not useful*.

Comment: Agree, however the question is broad if we would know what application server and the use case in more detail a more useful answer can be given.
The current directory can usually be set during the start up of the application server with an argument, so you for sure can create a deterministic way of accessing the files.

Comment: Then ask for clarification in a comment instead of giving a useless answer, and the current directory should *never* be used for anything in a multi-threaded multi-webapp web server. Webapp code should rely as little as possible on the state of the JVM, in order for multiple webapps to share a single web server (servlet container).

Comment: you are right.
For acessing files within your web application, use: getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt)

When using Tomcat as an application server, you can find out the base used by it using System.getProperty("catalina.base"). You could also create your own environment variable where you put the folder location in where your documents are stored.

Comment: Don't tell *me*. I already said that in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795258/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-a-file-in-java-servlet#comment68812811_40795258) more than 15 minutes ago!

Comment: You're a funny guy, if you dont want to discuss why start a discussion in the first place :)

Comment: I wasn't starting a discussion. My first comment was an explanation of why I down-voted your answer, i.e. it is *not useful*. First part of my second comment was supposed to be helpful to you, so you can learn to use this site better, i.e. when to create an answer and when to leave a comment. The second part was a followup trying to address the problem that just because you *can* set the working directory, doesn't mean you should use it. My last comment was *hinting* that if you have a good answer to replace your bad answer, don't tell *me* in a comment, but perhaps update the answer instead.